# Get static text font style in UI XCTests

Tags: ui-automation, xctest, ios-ui-automation

Does anyone know, how (if possible) to get font style for static text element?
I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with XCTest UI tests - the framework is deliberately designed so that you can't access non-functional properties of elements such as color and style. This is to encourage you to use the UI testing framework to write functional integration tests.

Checking the style of a label should be done in a unit test, where you will be able to access these properties of the UILabel.